# Equivalence relation for $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

In set $\mathbb{N}$ introduce and equivalence relation such that the set $\mathbb{N}$ becomes partitioned to three classes of equivalencies, which form the corresponding quotient space.

So I’m a little confused by the question. Since by definition, every partition of $\mathbb{N}$ corresponds to an equivalence relation, is it valid to do something like $\{\emptyset\}\bigcup \mathbb{Z^+}\bigcup\{0\}$?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Exactly that, no; the emptyset is not usually regarded as an equivalence class

Comment: Ok great so I need to rework this and replace the empty set with something else then?

Comment: An immediate one for this (and generalizable to an equivalence with $n$ classes) is to make $$x \sim y \quad\text{iff}\quad x=y \pmod{3}.$$

Comment: To emphasize, *any* partition of the set corresponds to an equivalence relation with those parts as the equivalence classes, and vice versa.  It won't necessarily be that the equivalence relation will be easy to convey in words however.  Those equivalence relations which are easy to explain hold special significance to us due to their "*elegance*" and so they may in some circumstances be preferred... but that doesn't make them any more or less of relations than others.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. First and foremost, you are asked to give an equivalence relation, not a partition. True, every equivalence relation corresponds to a partition and vice versa, but they are not the same things.

Unfortunately, if you put $S_{1}=\emptyset$, $S_{2}=\mathbb{N}^{+}$, and $S_{3}=\left\{0\right\}$ and you define as usual $$x\sim y\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \exists 1\leq i\leq 3: x\in S_{i}\ni y$$
you get an equivalence relation with only two equivalence classes! The reason for that is that your partition is not really a partition. One of the conditions in the definition of a partition is that all sets involved are non-empty. This shows clearly why: $S_{1}$ does not lead to any equivalence class.

Comment: ok I think I get it. Obviously the empty set cannot be considered here since by definition it must be non empty. So finding something else to replace the empty set but keeping my other two sets will form the proper partition?

Comment: No. If you keep $S_{2}$ and $S_{3}$ as is, then whatever non-empty third set you choose would have a non-empty intersection with either $S_{2}$ or $S_{3}$. This would mean that you again don't have a partition, because the sets in a partition by definition are mutually disjoint.

Comment: Now I don’t get it. Am I allowed to separate the set of positive integers into the set of positive even integers and positive odd integers? If so, then how do they have a non empty intersection?

Comment: You are definitely allowed to do that, but then you haven't kept $S_{2}$, as you suggested in your previous comment.

Comment: Ohh my bad you are right. Ok cool thank you for the help.